# JSON parsing error in django post request

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to send data through POST request in django

```
url = 'http://db-003:8013/v1/upgrade-ce'
payload = {
           "cluster_name": cluster_name,
           "cec_id": cec_id,
           "new_version": new_version,
           "cr_number": cr_number,         
          }

response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

On receiver end post method:

```
cluster name = request.data.get('cluster_name')
```

*Data on receiver's end*

```
<QueryDict: {'cluster_name': ['abcd'], 'cec_id': ['abc'], 'new_version': ['8.0.23'], 'cr_number': ['6587657']}>
```

The obtained data is a list, and not an individual string string.
Tried `json.dumps()` , but on the receiver end, data is empty.

How do i get an individual string

Comment: `request.data.get('cluster_name')` or `request.data['cluster_name']`. The `QueryDict` implement subscription and `.get(...)` to return the *last* element of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending Content-Type as application/json in headers and json.dumps(payload) should work.

```
url = 'http://db-003:8013/v1/upgrade-ce'
payload = {
           "cluster_name": cluster_name,
           "cec_id": cec_id,
           "new_version": new_version,
           "cr_number": cr_number,         
          }

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```